# GraphQL search: How to query using a list of ids?

Tags: graphql, field

I have the following `GraphQL` statement. This `GraphQL` statement searches through our pages, filtering on a specific page type, and then filtering on if a specific `droplink` field contains either of two `IDs`.

I would like to be able to pass an argument to this query, `$contentTypes: [String!]`, and  have the query search if the `droplink` field `itemContentType` contains any of the `IDs` in that array. How can I accomplish this in `GraphQL`?

```
query CDL($numberOfItems: Int!) {
  test: search(
    where: {
      name: "_templates",
      value: "97248DF8048C4D2DB07E7369DC24AC98", #hasItemContentType
      operator: CONTAINS
      
      OR: [
        {
          name: "itemContentType",
          value: "0BE12932EC9C4156BFD9C63A7F271CB3", #Story
          operator: CONTAINS
        },
        {
          name: "itemContentType",
          value: "3A7F440833084217B9E125A29B533535", #Article
          operator: CONTAINS
        }
      ]
    }
    first: $numberOfItems
    orderBy: { name: "name", direction: ASC }
  ) {
    total
    results {
      name
      displayName
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i'm trying to return a collection of items for a given array of item ids.  surely I don't just call graphql x number of items for the given IDs in my array?

Comment: @nologo Kind of. We found that it was necessary to use some sort of graphQL extension, like Apollo, in order to do it. I didn't end up implementing that solution, so i don't have all the details. https://www.apollographql.com/